# Using 'str' method on all values of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which holds objects in its values. I would like to use the `str` function on the dictionary, so that it will recursively run on all the other objects in the dictionary.

For instance, I have the following object:

```
>>> class Temp(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._item = 8
...     def __str__(self):
...         return str(self._item)
... 
>>> t = Temp()
>>> str(t)
'8'
```

I create a dictionary and put the object in it:

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> dict['object'] = t
```

Now, when I use the str function on the dictionary I get the following:

```
>>> str(dict)
"{'object': <__main__.Temp object at 0x7fa08889f910>}"
```

But I would like to get this:

```
>>> str(dict)
"{'object': 8}"
```

Comment: Would the dictionary contain another dictionary as value?

Comment: @Peter. I'm pretty sure that would still end up using repr rather than str

Comment: @MadPhysicist you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict`, like most other built-in container classes, uses the `__repr__` of an object when stringifying itself. While a missing `__str__` will fail over to `__repr__`, the reverse is not true: `__repr__` does not fail over to `__str__`.

The simplest way to obtain the result you want is to rename `__str__` to `__repr__`:

```
class Temp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._item = 8
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._item)

print({'object': Temp()})
```

results in

```
{'object': 8}
```

At the same time, the normal string representation will be as before because of the failover:

```
print(Temp())
```

results in

```
8
```

Keep in mind that `print` calls `str` on its positional arguments.

Comment: Correct, but making the `repr` of your class be either string representation of its wrapped object is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Davis. Why? What do you think a scalar numpy array does?

Comment: Because `repr` is supposed to be `eval` to an equal object (or be obviously not `eval`lable at all).

Comment: @Davis. it's not really supposed to, and generally doesn't, although for many simple containers it happens to. Repr is just supposed to be a meaningful representation of the state. If the entire purpose of the object is to be a wrapper for the item it contains, this sort of repr is fine. +1 to your answer of course though.

Comment: @Davis. In context of your answer, I see your point. In a sense, this answer explains why OP's expectation does not pan out, while yours provides a correct workaround.

Comment: There are guidelines in the docs: _If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned._

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you want a `dict` subclass:

```
class strdict(dict):
  def __str__(self):
    return "{%s}"%', '.join("%r: %s"%p for p in self.items())
```

Consider using `iteritems` in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might help. Instead of assigning 't' directly like you have done below.

```
>>> dict['object'] = t
```

You can typecast it and then save it into the dictionary. Like this

```
>>> dict['object'] = str(t)
```

Then, the dictionary will have the value you require.

```
>>> str(dict)
"{'object': '8'}"
```

Comment: I think they want to be able to store the objects in the dictionary and visualise the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind iterating over the dict, we can write a replacement for str:

```
def nerez_str(d):
  new_d = {}
  for k, v in d.items():
    new_d[str(k)] = str(v)
  return new_d
```

now instead of calling `str` on your dict, pass it to `nerez_str`.

We may make the function recursive, if you are expecting your dictionary to contain other dictionaries as values.