# Type hinting enum member value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

For an enum `Foo`, How could one type hint a variable that must contain a member value (not the member itself) of some Enum-- e.g. a value such that `Foo(x)` will return a valid member of `Foo`?

Here's a simplified version of my motivating example:

```
class DisbursementType(Enum):
    DISBURSEMENT = "disbursement"
    REFUND = "refund"
    ROLLBACK = "rollback"

class SerializedDisbursement(TypedDict):
    transaction_type: ???
    id: str
    amount: float

a: SerializedDisbursement = {"transaction_type": "refund", id: 1, amount: 4400.24}
```

I would really like to avoid simply typeing `transaction_type` as `Literal['disbursement', 'refund', 'rollback']` as that would be quite prone to getting out of synch over time.

Comment: I don't think there is anyway to express what you want in Python's type hinting system. Probably `Literal` would be your best bet...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most widely compatible option is to just have an assertion that validates that the literal type doesn't go out of sync with the enum values:

```
class DisbursementType(enum.Enum):
    DISBURSEMENT = "disbursement"
    REFUND = "refund"
    ROLLBACK = "rollback"

DisbursementValue = typing.Literal['disbursement', 'refund', 'rollback']

assert set(typing.get_args(DisbursementValue)) == {member.value for member in DisbursementType}

class SerializedDisbursement(typing.TypedDict):
    transaction_type: DisbursementValue
    id: str
    amount: float
```

This ensures maximum compatibility with static analyzers, but requires repeating all member values. Also, the assertion cannot be checked statically.

---

Other options break static analysis. For example, if you use the [functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) to create the enum from the literal type:

```
DisbursementValue = typing.Literal['disbursement', 'refund', 'rollback']

DisbursementType = enum.Enum('DisbursementType',
                             {name.upper(): name for name in typing.get_args(DisbursementValue)})
```

then mypy [doesn't understand](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=32a7f87fc2e1a53c88d08e0f4843a9cc) the enum, and at that point, there's little point having annotations at all.

Similarly, if you try to use non-literal type arguments for the `Literal` type:

```
DisbursementValue = typing.Literal[tuple(member.value for member in DisbursementType)]
```

then [that breaks too](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=0f2f1d2df7afa1a5978894bdb3118ae6).

Comment: That works! I can deal with the minor dis-ergonomic factor of hand-keying the values twice, but not the bug-promoting factor. With a simple helper to do the assertion, this takes me there.

Comment: Mypy not understanding the Enum functional API is a major problem, it basically coerces you to declaring Enums with class syntax whenever possible.

Comment: @bad_coder: It understands the functional API, but only "static" uses of it - the second argument has to be a literal. It can't evaluate arbitrary runtime expressions to figure out the names and values.

Answer (score 3):

While this doesn't answer the question as asked, I think you might also reconsider why you're using a `TypedDict` with a string instead of a proper class to hold the enum (instead of a `str`, since `DisbursementType` really does seem like an *enum*), and which can then employ some custom serialization logic.

For example:

```py
import dataclasses as dc
import json
from enum import Enum


class Transaction(Enum):
    DISBURSEMENT = "disbursement"
    REFUND = "refund"
    ROLLBACK = "rollback"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


@dc.dataclass
class Disbursement:
    transaction: Transaction
    id_: str
    amount: float

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(dc.asdict(self), default=str)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    disbursement = Disbursement(
        Transaction.REFUND,
        "1",
        4400.24,
    )
    print(disbursement)
```

```
$ mypy example.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
$ python3 example.py
{"transaction": "refund", "id_": "1", "amount": 4400.24}
```

Alternatively, you can have your enum inherit from `str` and simplify a few things:

```py
import dataclasses as dc
import json
from enum import Enum


class Transaction(str, Enum):
    DISBURSEMENT = "disbursement"
    REFUND = "refund"
    ROLLBACK = "rollback"


@dc.dataclass
class Disbursement:
    transaction: Transaction
    id_: str
    amount: float

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(dc.asdict(self))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    disbursement = Disbursement(
        Transaction.REFUND,
        "1",
        4400.24,
    )
    print(disbursement)
```

Other considerations:

- Python 3.11 will have `StrEnum`: https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/enum.html#strenum
- Notes on subclassing enum: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#others
- Equality comparisons with strings should probably be avoided: https://www.cosmicpython.com/blog/2020-10-27-i-hate-enums.html (prefer `Disbursement.transaction == Transaction.REFUND` to `Disbursement.transaction == "refund"` or `str(Disbursement.transaction) == "refund"`
- Inheriting from `(str, Enum)` may have some drawbacks: [How to deserialise enumeration with string representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65339635/how-to-deserialise-enumeration-with-string-representation)

Finally, I wanted to note that defining `__str__` on my Enum did *not* do what I expected it to do using your `TypedDict` example above; that's because [str(mydict) calls `repr` to provide each of `mydict.values`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53909452/1588795):

```py
class Example:
    def __repr__(self):
        print("I called repr!")
        return "from repr"

    def __str__(self):
        print("I called str!")
        return "from str"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"example: {Example()}\n")

    d = {"example": Example()}
    print(f"in a dict: {d}")
```

```
$ python3 foo.py
I called str!
example: from str

I called repr!
in a dict: {'example': from repr}
```

Additionally, you can't add custom methods to a `TypedDict`; if you change `Example` to inherit from `TypedDict` and rerun that last example, you'll see that neither `__repr__` nor `__str__` is called, and unfortunately there is no runtime error either (`mypy` helpfully warns `error: Invalid statement in TypedDict definition; expected "field_name: field_type"`). Because serialization logic seems to belong to `Disbursement`, I changed it to a somewhat similar class that allows me to customize its `__str__`: a dataclass.

Comment: I'm afraid your suggestions are coming at the problem backward. The serialized disbursement comes off the wire from non-Python and passes through framework code which transforms it into a plain old dict. Certain portions of my logic are plugged into the framework and must interact with those rawer data, outside of my core business logic which can later enliven it into a full Disbursement object. My use of TypedDict is to apply some structure to that P.O.D.

Comment: @Nentuaby Perhaps you could have explained your requirements better -- for example "`SerializedDisbursement` must be a dictionary, and this design decision is outside of my control." Is there any additional information you can provide about what aspects of this problem you can and cannot control? It would seem like you agree that the use of a dictionary here would be an inferior way to go about it, if you had the freedom to do otherwise.